# How do I pass artifact or build variables to a release in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a release artifact that is created by a build. I want to distribute the artifact using a release pipeline. Ideally, the build would automatically trigger creating the release. However, I need to supply some variables (which are identical to the ones in the build) to the release. I can enter them when manually triggering the release:
[manual create release dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xylL.png)

Is there a way to pass the variables automatically, either via the triggering build or via the artifact?

Answer (score 0):

basically, you need to look at [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) and [artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops). Also look at the general ideas behind [release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops).

One way of achieving what you need, is using "build name" as the release variable (its available "for free" from the release if the release is linked to an artifact\build). there might be other options as well, depending on your setup.